# RoR nested categories

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, nested, url-routing

folks!
I wonder how to make url like: site.com/coding/ruby/rails/article-name 
As you can see there is nested category. I've already looked at acts-as-tree and awesome nested sets, but it makes urls like site.com/rails/article-name.

So, please help me

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use a resource-ful controller, make a route like this:

```
scope '(*categories)' do
  resources :articles
end
```

this will require using 'article' at the end of your urls: /coding/ruby/rails/articles/article-name

or you can use a route like this:

```
match '(*categories)/:id' => 'articles#show', :as => :article
```

this will let you do article_path(:categories => 'coding/ruby/rails', :id => article.friendly_id)

to get /coding/ruby/rails/article-name

If you are using awesome_nested_set, you could generate the categories string by doing something like

```
article.category.self_and_ancestors.join("/")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [Friendly-id](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id).

Comment: tnx, I already tried this gem. The main problem is maintaining "breadcrumbs"  in url (nested url). I haven't any problems with converting rails/1 to rails/article-name

Answer (score 0):

To set this up, you start with a route that does "route globbing":

`match "*category" => "categories#show"`

or

`match "categories/*category" => "categories#show"`

in your controller, you will receive all the parts of of the url through the `params` hash. To keep things clean, define the search logic in your model

```
def show
  @category = Category.find_recursive(*params[:categories])
end
```

in your model, define a method to find the category. I am assuming acts_as_tree is defined in your model

```
def self.find_recursive(*categories)
  children = roots
  last = nil
  categories.each do |category|
    return unless children

    last = children.find_by_permalink(category)
    children = last.children
  end
  last
end
```